# Connecting Salesforce Marketing Cloud to Amazon Web Service (AWS/S3)

Tags: marketing-cloud, aws, amazon-s3

I want to import files that are located in a Bucket on AWS S3 scheduled into the Marketing Cloud, but can not get this running.

What would be the correct file location to choose and how would the set up look like?

I could imagine that this Case is quite common Use Case.

Has anybody done this already or has an idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: What does *"can not get this running"* mean?  Are there error messages?

Comment: Yes I receive "The import instance could not be validated for the following reason(s): UnexpectedError" - but I reckon that my file location is not correctly set up for connecting with AWS..

Comment: @Christian I have the same question. Do you have any resolution to this? How to set up the S3 as a file location with Private/Public keys? What are those keys? Thanks!